# How do I test this third party API integration in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr

My project is a rails app that extends some third party API.  A lot of the requests rely on third party API calls.  How should I test these cases in rspec?  Should I use VCR and actually just hit the third party (then mock future requests)?  Or should I just download the payload into a fixture manually and stub requests with webmock and find a way to bypass the oauth process?  Are the better solutions?

Note that it uses OAuth, but I don't use omniauth.

Sometimes the API limits me to fetching N records at a time, so I have to paginate them.  There could be instances where I'm making 25 requests just to get the data I need, but this is mostly for the sync rake tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to download a payload manually, as this is exactly what VCR does for you. VCR creates a yaml fixture, that it uses for all future requests.